# jQuery or JavaScript use an embeded string in element as function reference

Tags: javascript, function

Is it possible to have lets say, a link where I have it look like

```
<a href="something/" class="something" data-callback="thisFunction">
<a href="something/" class="something" data-callback="thatFunction">
<a href="something/" class="something" data-callback="anotherFunction">
<a href="something/" class="something" data-callback="">

<script>
     $('.something').click(function(e)
     {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cb = $(this).data('callback');
        if(cb !== undefined && cb !== null && cb !== '')
        {
           //somehow use cb as a means to call another function
           //similar in effect to calling "thatFunction();"
        }
     });
    function thisFunction()
    {
       //code
    }
    function thatFunction()
    {
       //code
    }
    function anotherFunction()
    {
       //code
    }
</script>
```

If it is possible, how would I achieve making it work, and what is the actual reference for that type of call like what is the method called for doing that so in the future if I forget hopefully I'll I remember what the method is called and I can just look that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
window[cb]();
```

Or to be on the safe side:

```
typeof window[cb] === "function" && window[cb]();
```

Answer (score 0):

in your example you can call this callback functions from window object. Something like window[cb]. But this isn't a good practice to assign such kind of global functions. I'd suggest you to wrap your callbacks in some object.